# Avril Lavigne, Michelle Branch, and ____ (who was the 3rd similar singer from that time period?)

Tags: similar-artists

I seem to recall that Avril Lavigne got mainstream attention in the US in the early 00's and shortly thereafter 2 other female singers of about the same age came out, both of whom were not "skater punk" like Avril, yet to some extent seemed to compete for the mostly the same listener base.

One of the other 2 singers I'm thinking of is Michelle Branch. Can anyone help me think of who the 3rd one must've been?

Clearly Avril was the most famous of these 3 and I think that whoever the 3rd one is was more similar to Michelle Branch in terms of style and comparative fame.

I seem to think also that she played piano in one of her songs and/or videos...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Vanessa Carlton?

I remember watching this VH1 feature ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7WPQRJ_LiF0 ) of those three artists back when they were new on the scene.